# Marcar o maior e menor valor de uma coluna com kableExtra no R

Tags: r, rmarkdown, formatação-condicional

Estou construíndo um relatório em Rmarkdown e preciso criar uma tabela com o data table abaixo:

```
MEDIA <- data.frame(Questões = c("Questão 43", "Questão 44", "Questão 45", "Questão 46", "Questão 52", "Questão 53"), 
                    Média = c(5.03, 5.00, 5.06, 3.80, 4.22, 4.49))
```

Para criar a tabela, uso o pacote `kable` e estou tentando usar o pacote `kableExtra` para criar uma espécie de *formatação condicional*. Minha ideia é que a tabela pinte apenas o maior valor de verde e o menor de vermelho, para que eu não use `arrange()` e altere a ordem da coluna *Questões*. Escrevi o código abaixo:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, options(digits = 3))
MEDIA %>%
    kbl() %>%
    kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(2, color = ifelse(max(MEDIA$Média), "green", "red"))
```

Mas o código me retorna todos os valores em verde. É possível fazer essa formatação com o kableExtra, ou algum outro pacote do R?

Answer (score 2):

Para o `ifelse` functionar como pretendido, tem que ter uma condição lógica e não tem. `max(MEDIA$Média)` não está a ser comparado com os valores desse vetor.

Como está não é sequer um valor lógico:

```
max(MEDIA$Média)
#[1] 5.06
```

Como deve ser:

```
MEDIA$Média == max(MEDIA$Média)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

O código fica então assim.

```
library(kableExtra)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, options(digits = 3))
MEDIA %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(2, color = ifelse(MEDIA$Média == max(MEDIA$Média), "green", "red"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!